# Вернуть значение промиса

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

Есть функция:

```
function funcName() {
  if (bool) {
    return 1
  } else {
    api.execute("api.name", { user: id }, (result) => {
      result.answer 
    })
  }
}
```

Как сделать чтобы функция возвращала result.answer полученный в промисе, либо присваивала это значение какой-то переменной вне. Если попробовать присвоить значение переменной - получим undefined. Как переписать этот пример, чтобы небыло конфликтов синхронности/асинхронности
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
async function funcName() {
  if (bool) {
    return 1
  } else {
    const result = await api.execute("api.name", { user: id });
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: возвращает [object Promise]

Comment: @Danil да, так и должно быть, всё правильно. Добро пожаловать в асинхронный javascript, учитесь работать с промисами

Comment: @Danil, далее используете промис `funcName().then(res => {})` или так же как в ответе.